# Why do all my libraries and lists have a pink design?

Tags: design, new-experience

I created a site collection on SharePoint online.
On the main page everything looks ok, but when I open any library or a list in the "new experience" style all of it has a pink design. In "classic experience" everything is ok.

But how can I apply the classic blue color to a new experience style?

There is how it seems:
[image: Pink style]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Change the Look in Site Setting!

http://itgroove.net/align/change-color-spo-modern-experience/

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For the modern team site, you can change the look by clicking cog/wheel icon.  You will be presented with some options:

[image]

[image]